# Is it advised to build all apps using fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the modern Android development, is it advised to completely move onto fragment-like development?

To build both mobile phones and tablets apps using fragments and not do differentiate between activity-solely and activity+fragment apps?

Are there any Google Android Team's official recommendation to completely move to "fragments" or not to completely move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to develop using fragments but if you want to provide the maximum number of consumers/devices with the best possible environment then you should switch to fragments. However if you really think fragments are the devils work you can stick to just Activity-based development and provide a sloppy looking UI.

As far as Googles' feelings go, I think this sums it up-

> Embedded Activities via ActivityGroup were a nice idea, but have always been difficult to deal with since Activity is designed to be an independent self-contained component instead of closely interacting with other activities. The Fragment API is a much better solution for this, and should be considered as a replacement for embedded activities.

For more info about fragment usage check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and for more of the design philosophy check out [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html).