# Action Bar Tabs without using Fragments?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

It is maybe quite a newbie question but anyway. Since Tabhost is depreciated I tried to switch to the action bar tabs but I have my problems using fragments. Is there a possibility to use activities within the action bar tabs anyway?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You really need to use Fragments. What are your problems using Fragments?

Comment: As I have already developed my App using Tabhost I face certain problems "converting" my tabs into using a fragment. My main problem among others :) is basically that there is no simple example on how to use Expandable List and fragments.

Comment: Post a question about ExpandableList and fragments... I bet you'd get some help.  :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're set on using Activities over Fragments you could just use an intent to launch your activity from your `ActionBar.TabListener`

```
startActivity(new Intent(thisActivity(), thatActivity.class));
```

You should also check out this comment about using [Fragments over Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235536/1167780)

Comment: Starting an activity by pressing an action bar tab would be ridiculous, as doing so would get rid of the tab and the action bar itself, replacing it with the contents of the other activity.

Comment: That's were subclasses come in, the idea is not ridiculous at all.

Comment: Actually this is exactly how Google I/O 2014 is [implemented](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java#L802). When an item in the navigation drawer is clicked an new activity is started, this recreates the navigation drawer. A class called `BaseActivity` is used to implement the navigation drawer for all classes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possibility to use activities within the action bar tabs anyway?

Fortunately, no.

That does not mean you have to use fragments, though. Your `TabListener` can do whatever it wants to affect the change in your UI. A brute-force solution would be to call `setContentView()` again, to dump all your old widgets and lay down a brand-new (presumably different) set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried it with the solution MrEngineer suggested but it happend what you said it would. Of course by just changing the View, my two windows are displayed but a lot of control is gone. Guess for providing the look and feel of the now depreciated TabHost i will have to use fragments.

Comment: I've tried this solution and it's possible but it's definitely a hack. The question is, given this isn't the optimal way to create a tabview, how badly does it affect the performance my app? I mean is it so bad of a solution that it's worth learning how to use fragments properly and rewrite my app using them?

Comment: @Kalaji: "how badly does it affect the performance my app?" -- there is no way to answer this in the abstract. You can use Traceview to examine the performance of your `setContentView()` calls. "I mean is it so bad of a solution that it's worth learning how to use fragments properly and rewrite my app using them?" -- I'd certainly use fragments. Fragments have been around for about three years, so it's not like it's something new. Then again, I wouldn't use action bar tabs, but rather a `ViewPager` with a tab-style indicator (`PagerTabStrip` or one from the ViewPagerIndicator project).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use an `Activity` with the `ActionBar`. Beware this is not intended behaviour though, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work perfectly.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

//@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ActionBarActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG  = getClass().getName();
    private Intent i    = null;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private Tab one;
    private Tab two;
    private Tab three;

    // create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (tab.getTag().equals("one")){
                Log.d(TAG, "tab one selected");
                i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), One.class);
                determineRun();
            }
            if (tab.getTag().equals("two")){
                Log.d(TAG, "tab two selected");
                i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Two.class);
                determineRun();
            }
            if (tab.getTag().equals("three")){
                Log.d(TAG, "tab three selected");
                i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Three.class);  
                determineRun();
            }           
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }
    };  

    // we only need to start the Activity if it's not actually already the current Activity!
    void determineRun(){
        if (!TAG.equals(i.getComponent().getClassName())){
            startActivity(i);
        }   
        return;
    }//end method

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setSubtitle(getResources().getString("subtitle"));        
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    
        one = actionBar.newTab();
        one.setText("Tab 1").setTag("one");
        two = actionBar.newTab();
        two.setText("Tab 2").setTag("two");
        three = actionBar.newTab();
        three.setText("Tab 3").setTag("three");                
        one.setTabListener(tabListener);
        two.setTabListener(tabListener);
        three.setTabListener(tabListener);

        // You will have to set the selected Tab manually
        // A good idea would be to create a subclass for each Tab based on this code
        // Then, just create a new Activity which extends ActionBarActivity
        actionBar.addTab(one, 0, false);
        actionBar.addTab(two, 1, true); // selected Tab
        actionBar.addTab(three, 2, false);
    }//end method

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");
        Log.d(TAG, ""+i.getComponent().getClassName());
        // again, here you need to select the Tab manually
        if (!TAG.equals(i.getComponent().getClassName())){
            actionBar.selectTab(two); // selected Tab
        }   
    }//end method

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()");
    }//end method

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }//end method    
}//end class
```

You probably want to override the animation in your `Activity` so the change of tabs is seemless.
To do so, modify the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` which extends ActionBarActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}//end method
```

Comment: These are not activities in action bar tabs. These are activities *started by action bar tabs* that then take over the screen. This does not relate at all to the OP's question.

Comment: it has the same effect, let's not nitpick about one word

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is correct, you want to use action bar to swap activity instead of fragment. in this case, please continue to read.

from the official document you can see, the actionbar feature defines a set of ui, position. if you want to implement actionbar with activity, the most important thing to do is 
1. to associate your tab(position) with your activity. 
2. add tablistener callback(instantiate your new activity, stop the current activity) every time the tab is click

the best design is to have the tablistener implemented a seperate class, so that each of your activity could use this class.