# Why Group Activity is Deprecated

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, tabactivity

I am Searching for the answer of my questions

**Why *Group Activity* is deprecated?**

I did not find any proper answer. My second question is

**Why we have to use *Fragment* instead of *Group Activity*?**

I need answer of these question in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your detailed answer by reading [The Android 3.0 Fragments API](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) blog. One of the relevant point is:

`Embedded Activities via ActivityGroup were a nice idea, but have always been difficult to deal with since Activity is designed to be an independent self-contained component instead of closely interacting with other activities. The Fragment API is a much better solution for this, and should be considered as a replacement for embedded activities.`

You can also look at [Is it advised to build all apps using fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234755/is-it-advised-to-build-all-apps-using-fragments) question. Hope it helped.